# Convert tensor of (row, column) coordinates to boolean mask in TensorFlow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have an array of 2D coordinates, from which I need to obtain a boolean mask with a known shape, where elements whose index is in the coordinates array is `True`.

For example, if I had an indices tensor which contains `[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 2]]` and a given shape of `(5, 5)` I need to get a matrix that is like so:

```
[[ True,  True, False, False, False],
 [False,  True,  True, False, False],
 [False, False,  True, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False],
 [False, False, False, False, False]]
```

In Numpy I'd do it like so:

```
idx = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 2]])
bool_mat = np.zeros(shape=(5, 5), dtype=np.bool)
bool_mat[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]] = True
```

However, in TensorFlow you can't assign tensor items like this.

How can I express an equivalent computation in TensorFlow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(tensor, indices, updates)`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

indices = tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [0, 1], [1, 2]])
bool_mat = tf.zeros(shape=(5, 5), dtype=tf.bool)

bool_mat = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(bool_mat, indices, tf.repeat([True], repeats=tf.shape(indices)[0]))
print(bool_mat)
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ True  True False False False]
 [False  True  True False False]
 [False False  True False False]
 [False False False False False]
 [False False False False False]], shape=(5, 5), dtype=bool)
```